# MySql stored procedure - add SELECT and UPDATE in 1 stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I try to call 1 stored procedure and do 2 things:

> CALL PING(1)

**update timestamp to row**

and also

**get back value from column**

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE ping (IN `P_in` INT)
BEGIN 
 UPDATE V_column SET my_timestamp=NOW() WHERE id=P_in;
 SELECT updateFiles FROM V_column WHERE id=P_in;
END
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: PS. The code itself is correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/h-qV_mW1